# Unable to store permanently the id of dragged item

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in which i had to store the the 3ID's of drop item in 3 textbox. but when i dragg and drop either one it stores it's id but when i drop the second item it stores it's ID but remove the ID of first from the textbox.

code

```
function dropItems(idOfDraggedItem, targetId, x, y) {

var targetObj = document.getElementById(targetId);  
var subDivs = targetObj.getElementsByTagName('DIV');    
if(subDivs.length>0 && targetId!='body')return; 
var sourceObj = document.getElementById(idOfDraggedItem);   
var numericIdTarget = targetId.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'')/1;
var numericIdSource = idOfDraggedItem.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'')/1; 

    if (numericIdTarget == '101') {
        document.getElementById('txt1').value = numericIdSource;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('txt1').value = "";
    }
    if (numericIdTarget == '102') {
        document.getElementById('txt2').value = numericIdSource;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('txt2').value = "";
    }
    if (numericIdTarget == '103') {
        document.getElementById('txt3').value = numericIdSource;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('txt3').value = "";
    }

    var fn = "Feeling1:-" + document.getElementById('txt1').value + ", Feeling2:-" + document.getElementById('txt2').value + ", Feeling3:-" + document.getElementById('txt3').value + "";

    document.getElementById('txt4').value = fn;

    if (numericIdTarget - numericIdSource == 100) {
        sourceObj.style.backgroundColor = '';
    } else {
        sourceObj.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
    if (targetId == 'body') {
        targetObj = targetObj.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0];
    }
    targetObj.appendChild(sourceObj);
}
```

Initialization (from comments)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var inp1=$("#txt1");
    var inp2=$("#txt2");
    var inp3=$("#txt3");
    $("#bttn").click(function(){
        if(inp1.val()=="" && (inp2.val()!="" || inp3.val()!="")) {
            alert("Provide answer in consecutive manner");
        } else if((inp1.val()=="" || inp2.val()=="") && inp3.val()!="" ) {
            alert("Provide answer in consecutive manner");
        } else {
            alert("Submit");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: i want when the user drag the item on the sepecified location it store it's ID and when they again drop the item to source they remove the ID from the textbox.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in here...

Comment: @Matthias : apologies i miss the jquery part. Below is the code using which i will alert the user ......  $(document).ready(function(e) {
 var inp1=$("#txt1");
 var inp2=$("#txt2");
 var inp3=$("#txt3");
    $("#bttn").click(function(){
  
  if(inp1.val()=="" && (inp2.val()!="" || inp3.val()!=""))
{
 alert("Provide answer in consecutive manner");
}
else if((inp1.val()=="" || inp2.val()=="") && inp3.val()!="" )
{
 alert("Provide answer in consecutive manner");
}
else
{
 alert("Submit");
}
  });
})

Comment: please don't post blocks of code in comments; it's hard to read and doesn't preserve formatting.  thanks to @Matthias for moving your code to the question.

Comment: @Claies: I am new to Stackoverflow. So don't have any idea.

Comment: just saying, you can edit your question instead of posting unreadable code, but since you didn't do that, @Matthias did it for you.

Comment: @Claies: Sure will keep in mind.. thnkx to matthias :)

Comment: where is your drag and drop function? Can you post your HTML code and full JS code as well?

Comment: I am using this js:  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/drag-drop-custom.js"></script>

Comment: Unable to paste full JS.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use jquery's built in draggable/droppable to acquire id's maybe this will help you with your current situation.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
                $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
                    drop: function( event, ui ) {
                        var id = $( this ).attr("id");
                        var container = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                        alert(id + " " + container);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .draggable{
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
                border: 1px black solid;
                margin: 0.5em;
            }
            .droppable{
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
                border: 1px black solid;
                margin: 0.5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="draggable1" class="draggable">
            <p>Drag me to my target</p>
        </div>
        <div id="draggable2" class="draggable">
            <p>Drag me to my target</p>
        </div>
        <div id="draggable3" class="draggable">
            <p>Drag me to my target</p>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 25px;"></div>
        <div id="droppable1" class="droppable">
            <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="droppable2" class="droppable">
            <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this help, make sure you have jquery included in your header: https://jsfiddle.net/s697v19g/

Comment: it works now... but my main concern is to store the Id of dragged items in a textbox when they are dropped and to remove the value of ID from textbox when they are dragged again.

Comment: i updated the code a bit to give you an idea of my approach. https://jsfiddle.net/s697v19g/1/